# vertical sliding text with fading text

Tags: text, scroll, sliding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A1Zv.jpg)

I need vertical continues scrolling text with middle text bigger in size and opacity 100%. Remaining should be as per attached image. I am trying this since long time, But unable to find solution. Some one please help me here.

Comment: http://srinivasputta.me/sliding.jpg
please refer above image for reference

Comment: Show what you have done so far and where is the problem you can't manage with. Also don't use comment - if you want to add something to question, just edit it. Read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @Arkej !

http://srinivasputta.me/vertical-carousel/
Pleasre refer above url. I need exact middle element highlighted (100% opacity) and remaining less opacity as attached screenshot or exactly as http://ge.com